# hide and show dynamically control based on checkbox value in asp.net

Tags: javascript

I want to have a javascript added to a checkbox that is created on the fly. And when this checkbox is toggle I want to hide or show the panels. These panels are also created on the fly.

There is a loop that put the id of the panel from the loop value

For example,

```
for (int a; a < mydataset[count]; a++)
  if (mydataset value is Textbox)
    Panel MyPanel = new Panel()

MyPanel.ID=Panel+myDataSet[count];  //so Panel1, or Panel2 based on the count.

if myDataSet.count=4
{
  Panel3.CssStyle=hidePopup; // I am able to hide the panel at runtime.
}

if (mydataset value is CheckBox)
  CheckBox myCheckBox=new CheckBox();
```

CheckBox // here I want to add a javascript function.  so when this checkbox is checked/unchecked some of the panel can be hide or show. There are 20 Panel. and instead of making all of them hide or show I need to hide 10 of them.  For example Panel1, Panel4 or Panel10.

`Panel3.CssStyle=hidePopup` works fine with this inline code.

```
<style type="text/css">
      .hidePopup
      {
          visibility: hidden;
          display: none;
      }

      .showPopUp
      {
          visibility: visible;
          display: block;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: what you actually need ? Do you want to show or hide pop up on check box click is am right?

Comment: @shafeeq if you edit the code, do it properly!

Comment: how many checkboxes are there? one for each panel?